# Flip an image without importing any library

Tags: python

I am attempting to flip a image using python without importing any library. Using the following code I am able to mirror the right hand side of the image to the left but the right hand side of the image remains unchanged.

I am stuck on getting the right hand side of the image to update.

```
height = len(image)
width = len(image[0])
            
for y in range(height//2):
    for x in range(width):
        pixo = image[x][y]
        pixn = image[x][-y]
        
       
        pixo.red = pixn.red
        pixo.green = pixn.green
        pixo.blue = pixn.blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use swapping:

```
pixo = image[x][y]
pixn = image[x][-y]

pixo.red, pixn.red = pixn.red, pixo.red
pixo.green, pixn.green = pixn.green, pixo.green
pixo.blue pixn.blue = pixn.blue, pixo.blue
```

Even easier thanks to @Mercury:

```
image[x][y], image[x][-y] = image[x][-y], image[x][y]
```

Comment: In fact, `image[x][y], image[x][-y] = image[x][-y], image[x][y]` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
height = len(image)
width = len(image[0])
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width//2):
       temp = float(image[i][j])
       image[i][j] = image[i][-j]
       image[i][-j] = temp
```

I think the problem was that you used a shallow copy and both parameters changed simultaneously, instead of that using `float()` to make a new object creates a deep copy.